# Decreasing an int by a percentage?

Tags: java, int, double, percentage

I am 99% done my program, but for one part I need to decrease a certain value (an int) by 90%. Initially I thought oh I can just multiply it by 0.1 and that will do it. But I can't because the value that is being decreased by 90% still needs to be an int after it is decreased by the 90%.

This is what I have, but it doesn't work for the reason stated above.

```
 s2.increaseAltitude(0.1*(s2.getAltitude()));
```

So my problem is I don't know how to go about decreasing the value by 90% but having it remain an integer.

Comment: No matter how you do it you'll have a rounding problem.  You need to establish the "rules" as to whether you round up, round down, round to nearest.

Comment: 10 is an int.  Why not write this: `s2.increaseAltitude(s2.getAltitute()/10);`

Comment: Or, if the given percentage has to be variable:  `s2.increaseAltitude((s2.getAltitude()*percent)/100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to cast the result of the operation into an `int`:

```
s2.increaseAltitude((int)(0.1*(s2.getAltitude())));
```

But this will round the result down since casting a `double` into an `int` will truncate the decimal part.

If you want/need to round up or down, then you could use `Math.round()`:

```
s2.increaseAltitude((int)(Math.round(0.1*(s2.getAltitude()))));
```

Comment: Except that that might lead to some surprising results.

Answer (score 0):

What about rounding it after computation :

```
s2.increaseAltitude((int) (0.1*(s2.getAltitude()) + .5));
```